# Unity Custom Voice Recognition

Tags: unity-game-engine, speech-recognition, speech-to-text

I'm am working on a Unity app that needs custom voice recognition. By custom I mean I cant have them be English or any known language. I want to teach the engine basically new words like gibberish words I made up and I need the voice recognition to recognize them, any ideas? Also I need it to work on both iOS/Android.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Check

https://github.com/cmusphinx/pocketsphinx-unity-demo

also the main cmusphinx website

http://cmusphinx.github.io